# How to include rails module in lib folder inside sidekiq worker class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm trying to call a method in a utility module I have in a rails 4 project. I use the module throughout my rails project for some activerecord behaviour, I recently added sidekiq to the project to perform some customer analysis on a daily basis but I can't seem to get the sidekiq worker to include the module at all.

This is what I have in the worker file:

```
require '../lib/utils/customer_utils.rb'
```

the location of the utility file is in:

```
lib/utility
```

And the module is written like so:

```
module CusomterUtils

def get_average_spend
..
end
...
```

Any idea on what I should be doing?

Thanks

Comment: try with `require 'lib/utils/customer_utils.rb'`

Comment: You have to use `require_relative` when passing a relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend following the [Rails autoloading convention names](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths), so either of these should work:

```
# lib/utils/customer_utils.rb
module Utils
  class CustomerUtils
    ...
  end
end
```

or

```
# lib/customer_utils.rb
class CustomerUtils
  ...
end
```

Typically the folder names are namespaces and the file name is the class name.

Note that the naming conventions changed over the versions of Rails, so `lib` may not be automatically loaded without a specific configuration option.

You could also use `require_relative '../lib/utils/customer_utils.rb'`.